# $P(x)\mid\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^{2^i} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, and $P(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x], \deg P=n$. Prove there exist $a_0,a_1,...,a_n$ such that $a_0^2+a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2 \not=0$  and $P(x)\mid \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^{2^i}$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! To attract answers to your question, please add some context and background information. For example, where did you encounter this problem (e.g. a book, class, real-life)? Please also show your attempt; seeing your work helps us help you. If this is homework, please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/23353).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $N=2^n$, $M=2^n+n$, $E=\mathbb{R}_M[x]$. The dimension of $E$ as vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ is $M+1=2^n+n+1$.

Let $U$ the subspace of $E$ spanned by the $x^kP(x)$, with $0\leq k\leq 2^n$. The dimension of $U$ is  $2^n+1$.

Let now $V$ the subspace of $E$ spanned by the $x^{2^m}$, $0\leq m\leq n$. The dimension of $V$ is $n+1$.

If we suppose that $U\cap V=\{0\}$, then the dimension of $U+V$ is $2^n+1+n+1$, strictly greater than the dimension of $E$, a contradiction. Hence $U \cap V$ is not reduced to $\{0\}$, and obviouly we are done.

Comment: Thanks you very much!, i'll be happy if i can understand this solution, i think my knowledge of algebra line is not enough. Can you show me what is $\mathbb{R}_M[x]$ ?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}_M[x]$ is the vector space of the polynomials with real coefficients, of degree less or equal to $M$. If you do not know vector spaces, this solution is not very convenient for you, sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much,   Kelenner. I understand, It's nice solution, can you tell me why you approach by vector space ? thank you.

Comment: I have remarked that your question can be see in this manner, its all. The question is "What is the structure behind this ?". Sometimes it works, and sometimes not...

Comment: @Road Human, A friendly reminder from your friendly community moderator: You should have posted this as a comment under Kelenner's answer. That's how we do it here! Roam the site for a while, and you'll learn about this (and many other things). I used my superpower to move it here together Kelenner's replies.